# Div won't let me edit its size?

Tags: html, css, sizing

So, I'm currently having an issue with a `div` tag in my HTML script. For some reason I can't seem to figure out how to adjust its size using margins, width, height, etc.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Change The Vibe</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .titleBox
        {
margin-left: 300px;
font-size: 36px;
margin-right: 300px;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: green;
margin-top: -50px;
width: 1000;
        }
        .titleHeader
        {
color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="titleBox">
      <h1 class="titleHeader">Change The Vibe</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I should also note that I am currently using dreamweaver to edit my script, so if that's related to my issue then I would like to know.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle where we can see how is currently working?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just realized my problem.

Comment: width: 1000; I forgot px.

Comment: what's the problem? what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need px after width.

```
width = 1000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to put this for your

```
        .titleHeader
        {
            padding-left:30px;
color: white;
```

and resize it as you see that 
try it please